# Manually create binary file C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a linked list of "1s" and "0s." Current if I write this out to a file it will save each 1 and 0 as the 8 bit representation of a one or a  zero. As an exercise for the student, the professor would like us to convert this manually to a binary file. I know there are libraries that can handle this, but those are forbidden in this assignment.

I'm looking for some direction on where to start. Can we just take the 1's and 0's and convert it to dec and output that to a file? Is that considered binary? Granted I would have to figure out a way to handle if the MSB is zero. Past this I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Please show the current code that is writing text and what you want to try.

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of the existence of any library that claims to do such a thing. Just curious, which exact library did you have in mind, that claims to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Yes, converting from a base-2 string (or a fairly arbitrary base for that matter) to a binary value is something C++ can do with input streams. If you have to do this yourself, hint: `int bit = inputChar - '0';` That plus bit-shifting using `<<` will get you a lot closer to the finish line here.

Comment: You can use the fstream library and just tell it you want to write it in binary. We're not allowed to do this. What we write to the file has to already be in a binary format of some kind. 

@stark there is no code at the moment. Currently if I just use fstream and write the contents of the linked list (or array for that matter) it will simply write it as a human readable file.... each value being an 8 bit representation of a 1 or a 0.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Comment: @tadman
Thank you! I assumed you have to use bit shifting of some kind. I just can't wrap my mind around how that will help. I have a very thorough understanding of binary. I've done a lot of work in assembly. But I'm stumped here!

Comment: The "write it in binary" as it relates to `std::fstream` has nothing to do with anything, here. And you must use this flag. Otherwise you will not be able to accurately write all bit patterns to a file, at least on Microsoft Windows. That flag does not exist, or is meaningless, on Linux, so if you believe that you can't use this flag, the only way to do this correctly would be on Linux. Which is why I believe this is a red herring.

Comment: Wait... I think I can figure it out from what you said. Basically I create something where my integer value "bit" actually gets the bits in my message... am I on the right track? In my head I was thinking there must be a "type" that only takes a single bit.

Comment: There is, but don't use it as it has all sorts of *weird* caveats due to internal architecture concerns that can be complicated to explain. Just do bit manipulation and your life will be a lot better. Work through the input "bits" in chunks of 8 characters, bit-shift each, and you're good to go. If you can be assured the input is *only* 0 or 1 you can do this super quick with a bitmask and some math.

Comment: @tadman 
thank you! I think I know where to go from here! Or at least how to get started!

Comment: @tadman Got it! It works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: It's worth adding a self-answer so others might benefit from your code, plus to help with your learning.